# RichFaces or PrimeFaces for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to move a java project to rails. Is there something like RichFaces or PrimeFaces for rails? Or I should use javascript?

Thanks,
Josep.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a lot of answers unless you explain a bit of what features you're expecting; most rails dev won't know what richfaces or primefaces are.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a set or widgets like menubar, slider, tree, panel, dock, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think a key point missing from these types of discussions (I've seen a couple of similar posts) is that PrimeFaces & similar libraries integrate well with Java beans.

When Rails developers respond with "why don't you use jQuery" etc. it is overlooking the fact that these types of libraries are distinctly different. Using a pure js solution will mean writing code to handle Ajax requests to post back to the server, whereas many of the Java UI libraries are tightly integrated with the beans & thus do not require any extra code to be written if your bean is already correctly integrated into the page. They are essentially widgets that are tightly coupled to your your backing code. In fact, many of these code packages are built on top of jQuery or some other similar js library. It's not that they are an alternative solution to javascript, they are just js with code hooks to glue back to your server-side logic.

I code in both RoR & Java and have not been able to find this type of functionality in RoR. It's one of the reasons I am migrating away from it. & as for RoR devs coming from a framework that values convention so much, I am not sure as to why they advocate pure js solutions to what is essentially a problem of tier integration (front-end to model/bean/business layer). If implemented correctly, this can save mounds of effort & PrimeFaces is a good out-of-the-box sort of solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are *Faces editors for eclipse/netbeans et al, but so far I haven't seen any **widget toolset** with visual editor support.

We have used [tabs_on_rails](https://github.com/weppos/tabs_on_rails) with success, the rest our applications all have javascript widgets such as [jquery token-input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) or the jquery-ui [date-picker.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use [PrimeRails](http://primerails.heroku.com), I am core developer of PrimeFaces and i did it for rails.